# Problema usando una relación ManyToMany en Django

Tags: html, python, django, django-models

tengo un problema al usar una relación ManyToMany con Django. Tengo una clase Usuario que especifica dicha clase en la bd, esta clase es la que tiene una relación de "Seguidos/Seguidores" que se supone que no es requerida para actualizar:

```
class Usuario(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=False, default='')
    apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=False, default='')
    nombre_usuario = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=False, default='')
    password = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=False, default='')
    fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField(blank=True)
    fecha_registro = models.DateField(blank=True)
    biografia = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    correo = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=False, default='')
    google = models.BooleanField(blank=False, default=False)
    
    seguidos = models.ManyToManyField('Usuario', related_name="seguidores", blank=True, default=[])
```

El serializer asignado a esa clase es el siguiente:

```
class UsuarioSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Usuario
        fields = ('id',
                  'nombre',
                  'apellidos', 
                  'password',
                  'nombre_usuario',
                  'fecha_nacimiento',
                  'fecha_registro',
                  'biografia',
                  'seguidos',
                  'seguidores',
                  'correo',
                  'google')
```

Ahora bien, en una view que edita el usuario, tengo lo siguiente:

```
def editarUsuario(request):
    usuario = Usuario.objects.get(id = request.session.get('idUsuario'))
    usuario_data = request.POST.dict()
    if request.POST.get('method') == 'PUT' :
        usuario_serializer = UsuarioSerializer(usuario, data=usuario_data)
        print(usuario_serializer)
        if usuario_serializer.is_valid():
            usuario_serializer.save()
    return cargarUsuario(request, usuario.pk)
```

El método usuario_serializer.is_valid() me devuelve siempre False. En el print se muestra lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He supuesto que esto es porque el valor de seguidores no tiene required=false, pero desconozco cómo puedo arreglarlo, si puedo insertar de alguna manera en usuario_data la lista de seguidores o simplemente añadir de alguna manera el required = false a ese parámetro. (Todos los demás datos vienen de un form en un html, en el cual creo que no puedo mandar la lista de seguidores)